# In SQL: How to concat hour and minute (stored as integers in a separate column) with the date part of a timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I'm building a **Grafana** dashboard where I need to apply a date filter.

I'm querying a Postgres database using **SQL** when I'm building the analysis and the date looks like the following:

| id | timestamp_column | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-16 16:00:00.000 | 1400 | 1900 |
| 2 | 2023-04-17 16:00:00.000 | 100 | 900 |

I would like the output to be the following in order for me to be able to use it as a filter:

| id | new_timestamp_start | new_timestamp_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-16 14:00:00.000 | 2023-04-16 19:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-04-17 01:00:00.000 | 2023-04-17 09:00:00.000 |

The timestamp column is of type *timestamp* and the start_time and end_time columns are of type *int* and note that the time 0100 and 0900 therefore is stored as 100 and 900.

Super thankful for all help!

Regards

Comment: You can add intervals to date part (like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1CeKB9nA)) but how are minutes represented? 950 means 9 hours and 50 minute or 9 hours and 30 minutes?

Comment: Thank you! 950 would mean 09:50 i.e 10 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with date and interval arithmetics:

```
select id,
    date_trunc('day', timestamp_column) 
        + start_time / 100 * interval '1 hour' 
        + start_time % 100 * interval '1' minute as new_timestamp_start,
    date_trunc('day', timestamp_column) 
        + end_time   / 100 * interval '1 hour' 
        + end_time   % 100 * interval '1' minute as new_timestamp_end
from mytable
```

The idea is to break down the integer column into hours and minutes using division and modulo, then perform the date arithmetics.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eMzPJpfr)** - I slightly modified the data so minutes come into play as well:

| id | new_timestamp_start | new_timestamp_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-16 14:00:00 | 2023-04-16 19:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-04-16 01:00:00 | 2023-04-16 09:50:00 |